# Is it really necessary to use the components provided by react-bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-bootstrap

I've tinkered with some React projects that utilize the **react-bootstrap** library, and I understand the normal way of writing up html is to do something similar to the following:

```
<Container>
  <Row className="mb-3">
    <Col md={6}>Hello</Col>
    <Col md={6}>There</Col
  </Row>
</Container>
```

I get that this looks pretty, but to me, it seems silly to use (and *import*) all these classes that essentially just output `<div class="whatever">...</div>`, *especially* because you still end up adding things like `className="mb-3"` to use utility classes. Is it considered heresy to just use **react-bootstrap** in the following manner?

```
<div className="container mb-3">
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col">Hello</div>
    <div className="col">There</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know that some elements, like `Form.Control` offer special functionality and should be used as components, but it strikes me as overly pedantic to import and use a whole component just to slap a single `<div class="col">` on the page.

I apologize if this is a stupid question, but I've googled around and haven't found any answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, unless...

- You want to control the grid (column count, ordering, etc.) dynamically with your model (which you could do manually, but yuck)
- You're using JavaScript features, because you're not loading the standard Bootstrap library file and they won't work

Presumably you're loading the standard Bootstrap CSS file, so anything that relies *solely* on that should work fine.